# Asignar un variable array de caracteres a una nueva variable

Tags: c

estoy trantando de asignarle el array a otra variable para obtener uno de los caractere en especifico, por un apuntador

```
int main(){
     char id[10];
     char *idn[10];
     FILE *in;
     fscanf(in,"%s",id);

     idn[10]=&id[10];
     printf("%s\n",*idn);
 return 0;
```

Comment: Hola Jorge,  puedes explicar cual es tu consulta?  Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboró una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: tengo array de caracteres y quiero asignarlo a otra variable

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que usted quiere es obtener un caracter de un array a usarlo desde idn puede tratar algo asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

     char id[10] = {'h','o','l','a'};
     char *idn;

     //FILE *in;
     //fscanf(in,"%s",id);

     idn = &id[0];   //<- tomas la posicion que quieres en este caso la 0

     printf("%c\n",*idn); //<- usas como formato %c

     printf("%s\n",id);

    return 0;
}
```

[Test-ideone](https://ideone.com/NxRali)

---

si usted lo que quiere es hacer una cosa similar a esta `arr = arr1` puede usar `snprintf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char id[10] = {'h','o','l','a'};
    char idn[10];
    //FILE *in;
    //fscanf(in,"%s",id);

    size_t des_size = sizeof (idn);

    snprintf(idn, des_size, "%s", id);

    printf("%s\n",idn);

    return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

[Test-ideone](https://ideone.com/6NJgbJ)

---

Podria emplear tambien `strncpy(idn, id, des_size);` pero tiene que tener en cuenta lo siguiente que dice la documentacion:

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if
>   source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not
>   be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would
>   overflow).

En el link puede ver un ejemplo de como manejar esta situacion.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy

Comment: bueno ahora si tiene un array de caracteres a copiar : char id[10] = {'h','o','l','a'};
     :) saludos!

Comment: Puede mirar sobre -> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ puede ver un ejemplo de su uso igual le ayuda para esa parte

Comment: @Elenasys jaja buena observacion Saludos